# A way to adapt the position of items in an android layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am currently work on an Android project, I have to show several check-box, now they are in a Relative Layout and all are positioned to their left neighbor.

So in landscape, I have a line of check-box, the problem is if I switch in Portrait the line is cut, because there are too many elements. So is there a simple way too automatically go to the next line when the element will be cut ?
I can change the layout type (relative, linear, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U may check this library [flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) coz u cant easily achieve this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I expected.